# Magento M2epro Rakuten 3rd party listing have duplicate products

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

We have added 14,779(7796 open products+6983 closed products) products in Rakuten. Please refer rakuten.png.We have added the products in Rakuten through New SKU feed. We didn't use service of M2ePro to add products in Rakuten. ie not used M2epro Rakuten template.

In magento,M2epro 3rd party listing added 71744 products. Most of the products are duplicates. These 3rd party products are added when cron ran.Please refer m2epro.png

Please let us know why such duplicate products coming in 3rd prty listing. We also try to remove all items from 3rd party listing and after removal we enabled cron, but 3rd party listing have same 71744 products with duplicates.

[image: Rakuten image]
[image: Magento-,2epro 3rd party listing duplicates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, we just disabled 3rd party listings. It was a bug in M2EPro that wasn't fixed for a long time.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the bug, with references if possible please?